# Unable to split json response?

Tags: java, json

This is my method

```
   public String buildJsonData(String username , String message)
    {
   JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("Username",username+":"+message).build();
   StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
   try(JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(stringWriter))
   {
  jsonWriter.write(jsonObject);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
System.out.print("buildJsonData ="+e);
   }
  return stringWriter.toString();
   }
```

If i input username as `john` and message as `hello`.I get output as

> {"Username":"john:hello"}

But I want output without braces and doublequotes I want my output as

> John:hello

I tried to split it using array[0] but didn't get the output.Is it possible in json to get my desired output(without braces and quotes).

Comment: If you don't want your result to be Json formatted, why are you writting it as Json ?

Comment: @Davz I am making a chat application and for that I need to have JSON.

Comment: @TruePS You don't seem to understand what JSON is. Or something. You say you need JSON, then ask how to ... not produce JSON ... with a JSON library.

Comment: @TruePS No, you don't _need_ to have JSON.  You have chosen to use it without really understanding what it is and how it is used.

Comment: I agree with the above comments: you need to study JSON objects (I recommend http://www.w3schools.com/json/ for a quick tutorial). As for how to do it properly: store username and message as separate objects in a json. Send it over the network. At the receiving end, unmarshal the JSON to get both entities and format them however you like.

Comment: @aleksG due to some reasons I can't explain why I need to use JSON but the thing is I am bound to use JSON and produce the desired output

Comment: @W.K.S Can you give me some practical example how to do that?

Comment: @TruePS If you absolutely must use JSON, I suggest you start by learning what it is and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sending end, you would put the Username and Message entities into a JSONObject and send the resulting string over the network.

On the receiving end, you would unmarshal the JSON to extract the entities. You can then format them however you like.

Please read about JSON encoding [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/).

This is a simple example:

```
private String getResponse(){

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {

    json.put("Username", "John");
    json.put("Message", "Hellow");
} catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
return json.toString();
}

private void receiver(){
try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(getResponse());
    String username = response.getString("Username");
    String message = response.getString("Message");
    System.out.println(String.format("%s : %s", username,message));

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is not really JSON.

A json structure would be like

```
{
    Username : "John",
    Message : "Hello"
}
```

Anf if your want to really use JSON, there is not way to remove braces and quotes. This IS Json.

If you want to output only the part you quoted, store the json value in a variable

```
String myoutput = stringWriter.toString();
```

And then remove the parts you don't want with replace() or a regexp

Comment: I am doing this via arguments the thing is I can only write JSOn object due to some reasons that's why it is not possible for me to convert it into string that won't work

Comment: I you have to use JSON, just use JSON. You can not use JSON as a string builder. Maybe you can parse the message on the client side ?

Comment: Can you give some examlple how to parse msg on client side

Answer (score 1):

Braces are part of the JSON notation - they indicate an object.  If you remove them, then it's not JSON any more.  Same goes for double quotes.You are creating your JSON object as:

```
Json.createObjectBuilder().add("Username",username+":"+message)
```

This creates an object with property named `Username` and value `john:hello`.  Again, this is the JSON notation.  It's not intended to be read directly, but to facilitate data transfer between applications (on the same or different devices).

If all you want to create is `john:message`, then instead of creating a JSON object, you should simply do:

```
String result = username + ":" + message;
return result;
```

Comment: due to some reasons i can't use strings